# open datagridview under textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to open datagridview right under textbox on another form, to make a combobox appearance. My code doesnt open datagridview in textbox location, because form where textbox is located is being opened in a tab control. Here is my code:

```
 Public counter As Integer = 0

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Select Case counter
            Case 0

                DGVForm.Show()
                DGVForm.Location = Me.PointToScreen(New Point(Textbox1.Left, Textbox1.Top + 20))
                counter = 1

            Case 1
                DGVForm.Close()
                counter = 0

        End Select

    End Sub
```

P.S.: Form1 has Tabcontrol - Form2 opens in that Tabcontrol. And DGVForm should open under Textbox1 of opened Form2.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Not exactly sure why you want to do so, but that's a different question i guess. Can't give you the exact answer, but you should first set the location and then show the form. The End User won't see a difference, but it improves the readability of your code.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. As I mentioned, form where textbox is located is being opened in a tab control. And looks like location of this form is set to It's location before If opens in Tabcontrol. And that's why datagrid can't be opened under textbox, because It takes location of textbox before opening in Tabcontrol.  I guess I'll need another design solution, just place datagrid under textbox and hide it. But that will cause issues on other things...